# Rails 5 how to resolve NoMethodError - undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass that occurs during minitest only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, haml, minitest

I'm trying to test my track_controller's index method and it keeps returning a `<500 Internal Server Error>`.

A track is created by a user is associated with said user. So `@track.user.name` should return the user's name. Yet the error is indicating that the `user` returns `nil` despite me explicitly assigning the user, what gives?

Test log:

```
-------------------------------------------
TracksControllerTest: test_should_get_index
-------------------------------------------
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 701806347], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mTrack Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "tracks".* FROM "tracks" WHERE "tracks"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 980190962], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mSAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[36mTrack Update (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "tracks" SET "user_id" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "tracks"."id" = ?[0m  [["user_id", 701806347], ["updated_at", "2018-12-11 14:30:49.753966"], ["id", 980190962]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mRELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-12-11 14:30:49 +0000
Processing by TracksController#index as HTML
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mSAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[36mCart Create (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[32mINSERT INTO "carts" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)[0m  [["created_at", "2018-12-11 14:30:49.856142"], ["updated_at", "2018-12-11 14:30:49.856142"]]
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[35mRELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  Rendering tracks/index.html.haml within layouts/application
  [1m[36mTrack Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "tracks".* FROM "tracks" ORDER BY created_at desc[0m
  Rendered tracks/index.html.haml within layouts/application (23.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 51ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)

NoMethodError - undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass:
  app/views/tracks/index.html.haml:20:in `block in _app_views_tracks_index_html_haml___68907435507065187_70307785248520'
  app/views/tracks/index.html.haml:8:in `_app_views_tracks_index_html_haml___68907435507065187_70307785248520'
  test/controllers/tracks_controller_test.rb:17:in `block in <class:TracksControllerTest>'
```

tracks_controller_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'
include Warden::Test::Helpers
class TracksControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest



  setup do
    @user = users(:cscades)
    login_as(@user)
    @track = tracks(:one) #need to sign in the users in order for tracks to be deleted as only track creators can delete them
    @track.user = @user
    @track.save!

  end

  test "should get index" do
    get root_path # root path == tracks#index
    assert_response :success
  end
```

track_controller.rb:

```
class TracksController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, raise: false
  before_action :set_track, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  # GET /tracks
  # GET /tracks.json
  def index
    @tracks = Track.all.order("created_at desc")
  end
```

index.html.haml (for tracks) error occurs on line indicated below:

```
- content_for :header do
  %section.hero.is-warning
    .hero-body
      .container
        %h1.title
          Browse the newest Tracks
.track-index-grid.pt4
  - @tracks.each do |track|
    .track.border-light
      .track-thumb
        -unless track.image_url(:thumb).nil?
          =link_to image_tag(track.image_url(:thumb)), track
        - if track.genre
          .condition
            %span.tag.is-dark
              = track.genre
      .pa3
        %h3.fw7.f4.title= link_to track.name, track
        %p.has-text-gray.fw7.pt9
          Sold by #{link_to track.user.name, new_message_path(:recipient => track.user.email), :title => "Send an email to #{track.user.name}"} #ERROR OCCURS HERE
        %p.has-text-grey
          #{track.description}
        %p.f3.fw6.has-text-right.pt2.price= number_to_currency(track.price)
        - if track_artist(track)
          = link_to 'Edit', edit_track_path(track), class: "button is-small"
          = link_to 'Delete', track, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure ?" }, class: "button is-small"
```

users.yml (user fixtures):

```
cscades:
  name: Cscades
  encrypted_password: <%= Devise::Encryptor.digest(User,'password') %>
  email: cscadesbooking@gmail.com
# column: value
#
polocardigan:
  name: PoloCardigan
  encrypted_password: <%= Devise::Encryptor.digest(User,'password') %>
  email: cardiganbooking@gmail.com
# column: value
```

Comment: What kind of object does `users(:cscades)` return?

Comment: a user fixture, I'll update my question now

Comment: You shouldn't be duplicating questions. I won't down vote/report any of them. But to keep the questions as cleaner as possible please do not repeat them.

Comment: @fanta apologies, the previous ver question was obtuse (due to lack of understanding on my part). This ver. of the question is much more focused with additional details and explanation

Comment: How many tracks do you have? You're using the fixture `:one`, are there more? Try `puts Track.count` in your `setup` block.

Comment: I think you have other tracks in fixtures without defined users